# Understanding the Four Causes of Aristotle

Tags: metaphysics, aristotle, causality

I'd like to better understand some concepts from Aristotle's Metaphysics. I'd like to know what does he mean by a "substance" (Ousia), does he just mean anything that exists? Can any substance be "explained" by Four Causes? For example, does a seed (of a fruit) answer all four causes? Well, it has a matter, it's effective cause would be (from what I understand) soil, water, warmth... And it's final cause would be a tree? But I'm having trouble grasping what would the formal cause of a seed be?

I'd also like to know how are the Four Causes and Aristotle's principles of "Potentiality and Actuality" connected? From what I gather, the "final cause" is just an actuality of a substance, while a "formal cause" has that potentiality?

For some context: At my university Philosophy is a mandatory course, and we only covered "Metaphysics" from Aristotle, so I might be missing out on some concepts he might have explained elsewhere (though I've tried googling). Please do answer my questions and / or point me to something a beginner can understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Four Causes

Intrinsic causes:

- **Material**: answers "Out of what (*ex quo*) is it?"
- **Formal**: answers "What (*quid*) is it?"

Extrinsic causes:

- **Final**: answers "Why or wherefore is it?"
- **Efficient**: answers "Whereby is it?"

---

<sup>Adapted from [this answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/39643/2014) to the question "[What if anything does Aristotle's formal cause actually explain?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/39643/2014)" (which in turn was adapted from [this answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/34466/2014) to the question "[Is conception an Aristotelian efficient, or material cause?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/34442/2014)")</sup>

## Four causes' relation to actuality & potentiality

Aristotle discovered the four causes in order to explain that motion is possible (*contra* Parmenides, who denied the possibility of change) and that, despite there being a plurality of beings in the universe, there are stable beings (*contra* Heraclitus, who thought everything is in constant flux).

Since the real distinction between actuality and potentiality is so important to [Thomism](http://scholastic.us.to/24Thomisticpart2.htm), a good overview of Aristotle's solution to the Parmenides vs. Heraclitus controversy on change is given in Part II, "**The doctrine of actuality and potentiality and its applications** according to St. Thomas," of the free book [***The Essence & Topicality of Thomism***](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/4540).

Another good short work on this topic is Thomas Aquinas's [***On the Principles of Nature*** (*De principiis naturæ*)](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DePrincNaturae.htm).

From [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/36446/2014), the first part of this work overviews the Aristotelian philosophy of nature:

- **[The Modeling of Nature: Philosophy of Science and Philosophy of Nature in Synthesis](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/book/5302)** by [William A. Wallace, O.P.](https://isidore.co/calibre/browse/matches/authors/394) ([review](http://www.thomist.org/jourl/1997/974AAshl.htm))