# Why is knowledge knowledge of explanations?

Tags: aristotle, plato, ancient-philosophy, platonism

I am reading Aristotle. He seems to me to believe that knowledge is knowledge of explanations (causes - aitiai). But what ground is there for this belief? I cannot formulate a reason for this. I would highly appreciate it if you could please help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Aristotle: Demonstration](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#DemDemSci): "The subject of the *Posterior Analytics* is epistêmê. This is one of several Greek words that can reasonably be translated “knowledge”. There is a long tradition of translating epistêmê in this technical sense as *science*. We have scientific knowledge, according to Aristotle, when we know: 'the cause why the thing is, that it is the cause of this, and that this cannot be otherwise'. (*Posterior Analytics* I.2)"

Comment: Thus, in a nutshell, "proper" knowledge (scientific knowledge, episteme) is knowledge of *causes*: the reason why something is that way and not other. We have other kind of knowledge: knowledge of empirical, historical facts, practical knowledge, etc.

Comment: I see. Thank you. So I gather then that because scientific knowledge is knowledge of changeless things, scientific knowledge is knowledge of explanations?

Comment: but the links you have provided does not answer my questions

Comment: More or less... following Socrates (knowledge is mastering the proper definition) and Plato (knowledge is knowing the essence) for A "proper" knowledge is knowing the causes that can provide us the correct explanation and understanding.

Comment: Still, it does not answer my question. We do not know what Socrates really believed. Anyway, I am asking why proper knowledge is knowing the causes. You seem to be repeating my question in an indicative sentence

Comment: See also the post [Four Causes in Aristotle](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/76919/understanding-the-four-causes-of-aristotle)

Comment: I cannot formulate a reason for this. - you cannot because you have no question. aiteo - to aks, ask to self first.

Comment: What do you mean I don't have a question? Maybe I am missing some guidelines? Please let me know

Comment: The foundation of knowledge is understanding, something that *under* to thing -  question.  Asking a question is precedes to knowing, asking ability, question formulation - the cause of knowledge.

Comment: when you answer wright @and my nick, i ll got a notice that you had answered